# dropdownlist Insert always the default value

Tags: asp.net

I have one dropdownlist with data from database table and i want do insert with this ddl + 2 texbox field in another table . The insert work but always insert the default dropdownList witch displays first. wHat am i missing?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
                string query = "SELECT Id, NAME FROM PROFITCATEGORIES";
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        DropDownListCategory.DataSource = rdr;
                        DropDownListCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
                        DropDownListCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
                        DropDownListCategory.DataBind();

                    }
                }

            }

            protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBoxValue.Text))
                    return;
                string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
                string insertSql = "INSERT INTO profits(Value,DateCreate,IdCategory,IdUser) VALUES(@Value, @DateCreate,@CategoryId,@UserId)";

                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                    //параметризация се прави тук за да се избегне SQL Injection
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", TextBoxValue.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreate", TextBoxData.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryId", DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", cui.getCurrentId());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //пренасочваме заявката към същата страница за да се видят новите резултати и да се избегне проблем с дублиране на инсерт при рефреш на страницата
                    Response.Redirect("~/Profit.aspx");
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
                TextBoxValue.Text = string.Empty;

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you press the asp:button the page gets reloaded, and the code in the page_load method gets initialised again. That's why the default item is always inserted in your database.

Put this around your code in the page_load: **(if (!Page.IsPostback))**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 

               if (!Page.isPostback)
                {
                string connectionString = cs.getConnection();
                string query = "SELECT Id, NAME FROM PROFITCATEGORIES";
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        DropDownListCategory.DataSource = rdr;
                        DropDownListCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
                        DropDownListCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
                        DropDownListCategory.DataBind();

                    }
                }
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're re-binding the list on every page load. Wrap the data-binding code in an `if (!IsPostBack)` block.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      // Bind the list here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the AppendDataBoundItems property and set it to true, and only bind on PostBack:

[How Do I Add an Additional Item To a Databound DropDownList Control in ASP.NET?](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/281/how-do-i-add-an-additional-item-to-a-databound-dropdownlist-control-in-aspnet)

[ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx)